# php if statement if greater then 0 or equal to None

Tags: php

I'm stuck with the below code, I want to show a table if data exists and hide it if there's no data.

It's working good, but now I want to add 1 more clause which is, don't show if contains string "None"

```
<?php if($year_7_9>0 || None) { ?>
<tr>
  <td class="a-center" style="width:30%">Year 7-9</td>
  <td class="a-center">
    <strong>
      <?=get_values_for_keys(subjectArr(6,''), $year_7_9);?>
    </strong>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php } else {?>

<?php } ?>
```

What I want to achieve is if the field contains the word "None" , it should do the same like > 0

Comment: What is this, a "who can make my code for me the fastest" competition?

Answer (score 2):

Change the statement to this:

```
<?php if($year_7_9>0 || strpos($year_7_9, 'None') !== false) { ?>
```

or if you don't care if it's "none" or "None":

```
<?php if($year_7_9>0 || stripos($year_7_9, 'None') !== false) { ?>
```

Comment: nope still not working , its showing the data

Comment: Is it spelled with an uppercase "N"?

Comment: Or do you wan't the exact opposite? Try if($year_7_9<=0 && stripos($year_7_9, 'None') === false)

Answer (score 0):

Based on haggi's answer, shouldn't it be this?

```
<?php if($year_7_9> 0 && strpos($year_7_9, 'None') !== false) { ?>
```

This way both of them have to be true, so the test only passes if the variable is greater than 0 AND it does not contain the string 'None'.

Comment: its acctually check both to be fullfill, its suppose to be or , means show if above 0 or dont show if containts the word "None"